# Android Tesseract App crashes

Tags: android, tesseract

i am a beginner with tesseract andoid. i am making an application that extracts text from image, My application crashes at Tesseract code. can any one help please, i don;t know what is the error.

```
   TessBaseAPI baseApi = new TessBaseAPI();
   String DATA_PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"//tesseract//tessdata//eng.traineddata";

   String lang = "eng";
   baseApi.init( DATA_PATH,lang);
   baseApi.setImage(img);
   String recognizedText = baseApi.getUTF8Text();
   baseApi.end();
   TextView out = ( TextView ) findViewById( R.id.textView1 );
   out.setText(recognizedText);
```

Comment: Please post the logcat with the exception include.

Answer (score 1):

Giving the correct path is very important. please check the data path ..

String DATA_PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/tesseract/tessdata/eng.traineddata";

i am sure there is no need for "//" in this code line ..

Ensure that tessdata folder is properly established in the sdcard .
Rest can be said if logcat is provided..

Answer (score 0):

Do you compiled already tess-two with android NDK?